# Link Zend Framework 1.12 on Azure with a database on Azure

Tags: zend-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, zend-db, azure-web-app-service

I have a website, which i've built it with Zend Framework 1.12. Locally, i have set these parameters into application.ini file:

```
 resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
 resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
 resources.db.params.port = 3306
 resources.db.params.username = "root"
 resources.db.params.password = "root188"
 resources.db.params.dbname = "sgalpha"
 resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

I've uploaded this website to the Azure platform and i did the same with the database. My problem starts when i am trying to change the parameters in order to link the new database (on Azure) with the website (on Azure, as well).

Any advice please?

Comment: I just found this link...I've tried again with these new parameters but still nothing! http://www.dragonbe.com/2011/12/configuring-zend-framework-apps-for.html Anyone who already used Zend Framework with Azure?

Comment: The first thing that pops into my head is: have you checked if the ports are open?

Comment: Hello Janis! I am not sure about what you are saying. I am pretty new to the Azure!

Comment: did you deploy your site with these parameters? or for deployment you have changed host name? There is no database on `localhost` when you run in Azure Web-site